# Every prime power ideal in a Noetherian Ring of dimension one can be written uniquely as a power of a prime.

Tags: commutative-algebra

I am using Atiyah MacDonald to study commutative algebra and in Chapter 9, it says the following:

[image]

If you look at the paragraph after the proof of 9.1, you can see that to get unique factorization, we must also have that given a nonzero prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ and $n \neq m$, we have $\mathfrak p^n \neq\mathfrak p^m$. I was not able to see why this was the case. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What would Nakayama's lemma give you?

Comment: @AnginaSeng To invoke Nakayama's Lemma, we would need that the ideal $p$ is contained in the Jacobson Nilradical of $A$, which is only true if $p$ is the only maximal ideal in $A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show that the chain
$$\mathfrak p\supseteq\mathfrak p^2\supseteq\mathfrak p^3 \supseteq \cdots$$
is strictly descending.

Suppose instead that $\mathfrak p^{n+1}=\mathfrak p^n$ for some positive integer $n$.

Let $M=\mathfrak p^n$, regarded as an $A$-module.

Since $A$ is a domain and $\mathfrak p\ne 0$, we get $M\ne 0$.

Since $A$ is Noetherian, $M$ is finitely generated.

From $\mathfrak p^{n+1}=\mathfrak p^n$ we get $\mathfrak pM=M$, hence by Nakayama's lemma

$\;\;\;\;$  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama%27s_lemma#Statement

we get $aM=0$ for some $a\in A$ with $a\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;\mathfrak p)$.

But then $a\mathfrak p^n=0$, contradiction, since $a\ne 0$,$\;\mathfrak p^n\ne 0$, and $A$ is a domain.